# Const object handle as argument in function

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to write a function that accepts an argument that is a const object handle.

```
function void example(const MyClass ob);
    //--
endfunction
```

When i try to run this code I get an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected type name. The type 'MyClass' is defined at test.sv(1).
```

You can make a const object handle, but why you cannot do it in a function argument list?
By the way - I'm aware that this only be a const object handle, not const class object and it it's (unfortunately) immposible to make const class object in SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a **const object *handle***. There are **const class *variables***. Like any **const variable**, they get assigned a value once as part their declaration, and become read-only after that.

A class **variable** has a value which is the **handle** to a class **object**. You want to be able to copy a function argument with the handle that got passed in as an input to the function. If SystemVerilog allowed you to declare an argument as a const variable, you could not make an assignment to it.

There is the concept of `const ref` function argument, but that has very little value as that only prevents modification of the local argument variable. You can still write to any class member given a handle to the object.